# mac で and で locate したい

Tags: sh, macos

locate コマンドは文字列(パターン)を指定すると、それに合致するパスを持つファイルを列挙してくれるコマンドです。しかし、このコマンドは、複数パターンを指定すると or 条件で検索をしてしまい、また、 mac においては and で動作させるオプションはなさそうです。

#### 質問

- mac の端末から、文字列を複数指定すると、それらすべてに hit するようなパスを持つファイルを列挙したいです。これはどうやったら実現できますか?

Comment: grep コマンドなどと組み合わせるのはではなくて、locate コマンド単体で and 検索したいということですか？

Comment: 手許の Linux では `man locate` で `-A, --all` というオプションが説明されているのですが，これがないということなんですね．

Answer (score 1):

- Macということなので、 mdfind (SpotlightのCLI版)で `&&` を使う。(検索式は多少繁雑になります)
- locate 結果を grep で絞り込む。

あたりですかね。